# Return onActivityResult in ActivityA from ActivityB, started from child fragment of ActivityA

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, onactivityresult

I have two activities and one of them has two fragments.

I have **ActivityA** with its fragments: **Fragment1** and **Fragment2**, and both of those can open **ActivityB**.

Fragment1 is a *maps fragment* with markers, and Fragment2 is a *list*. Both markers and list items, when clicked lead to ActivityB, which is an *about activity* with information on the certain location on a map.

What I am able to do is this - open the the ActivityB, from Fragment1 using:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RESTAURANT_DESCRIPTION);
```

And then in my Fragment1 I get the result like this:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    switch(requestCode){
        case RESTAURANT_DESCRIPTION: 
            //calling my method
            ZoomToMarkerFragment();
            //maybe call reload method from ListFragment
            break;
        case ADD_RESTAURANT: // TODO
            break;
    }
}
```

And the **code above gives me the wanted result when I open ActivityB from Fragment1**, ie maps fragment, but what I would want to be able to do is go to marker fragment if it is open from Fragment2, ie list fragment.

I tried adding the code above in my parent ActivityA, but it did not work.

So, my question would be - **is there a way to return the result of ActivityB to ActivityA using onActivityResult, when it is open from either of its child Fragment1, or its child Fragment2**?

Comment: What is you fragment container in Activity A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In your `Activity`'s onActivityResult, call `super.onActivityResult()` and
- as well make sure that from your `Fragment` you do `startActivityForResult(..)` instead of getActivity().startActivityForResult(..) if you want the result to come in your fragment.
- Also if you are using `nested fragments`, the child fragment should call `getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(..)` so that the parent fragment will have its onActivityResult method called

Comment: What I want is to get my results in my parent activity, not the fragment, and I am starting with `startActivityForResult(..)`, not with `getActivity...`

Comment: Then do `getActivity().startActivityForResult(..)` from your `Fragment` and in your parent `Activity` you override the `onActivityResult` and not in your `Fragment`

Comment: I think this is it. Thanks